# Is it possible to change start and end points of subpathes on HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

About HTML5 canvas, I have a question.

Is it possible to change start and end points of subpathes  on HTML5 canvas?
I mean, I want to change a shape which I have already drawn by drag & drop.

Thanks in advance, for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like that? http://libcanvas.github.com/ui/path-changing.html

It is not so ease, you should do a lot of counts & redraws. The most correct way is to use canvas frameworks.

Comment: Yes, I exactly want to do this kind of drag and drop. I will check and try this libcanvas framework. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can write me at shocksilien@gmail.com , if you have any questions about it.